# Sqlite rows not outputing in php

Tags: php, sqlite

Hello i'm trying to echo all proxies from my sqlite database
Screenshot:

[image]

For some reason they dont output in the browser there are also no errors

When I run the sql command in a sqlite browser it works fine. (see screenshot)

```
$db = new SQLite3('proxies/http.db');
$results = $db->query('SELECT proxy FROM httpproxies LIMIT 25;');
foreach($results as $entry) {
echo $entry['proxy'];
}
```

I want it to echo all proxies, each on a new line.

Comment: Looks like you just ran the query, but have not yet grabbed the results.  http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.query.php

Comment: `print_r($results)` Try like: `while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
    var_dump($row);
}` but who know, what values are you using in `proxies/http.db` .... check your connection also, you can also use CATCH/TRY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use `While` insteadof `foreach` (you need `fetchArray`)

```
<?php
$db = new SQLite3('proxies/http.db');

$results = $db->query('SELECT proxy FROM httpproxies LIMIT 25;');
while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
    var_dump($row);
}
?>
```